# Cakephp 3 - sorting data for croatian language

Tags: mysql, cakephp

When sorting data in Croatian, the sorting result is inaccurate.
This problem does not occur when sorting data in English.
The problem creates diakrytic signs: Š, Đ, Č, Ć, Ž.

```
//for example   
$this->loadModel('BlogPosts');
$blogPosts = $this->BlogPosts->find('all')->order(['BlogPosts.title' => 'ASC'])->toArray(); 
 pr($blogPosts);
```

The sorting result is:

```
...[title] => Auris tristique vehicula urna idspe... 
...[title] => Bauris rutrum dolor ligula sed euismod ante... 
...[title] => Člass aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent...
...[title] => Corbi imperdiet sollicitudin lacus ut bibe...
...[title] => Morbi a ipsum et lorem venenatis luctus...
...[title] => Pellentesque euismod ante nibh eu viverra...
...[title] => Rellentesque tortor dolor semper vitae elit et... 
...[title] => Đonec semper orci nec egestas condime...
```

Sorting is incorrect. It should be:

```
...[title] => Auris tristique vehicula urna idspe... 
...[title] => Bauris rutrum dolor ligula sed euismod ante...
...[title] => Corbi imperdiet sollicitudin lacus ut bibe... 
...[title] => Člass aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent...
...[title] => Đonec semper orci nec egestas condime... 
...[title] => Morbi a ipsum et lorem venenatis luctus...
...[title] => Pellentesque euismod ante nibh eu viverra...
...[title] => Rellentesque tortor dolor semper vitae elit et...
```

Croatian alphabet:A, B, C, Č, Ć ,D, Dž, Đ, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, Lj, M, N, Nj, O, P, R, S, Š, T, U, V, Z, Ž

How to solve this problem?

Comment: That's first and foremost a DBMS related problem, please add information / tag your question accordingly to the DBMS that you're using.

Comment: "Dobrodošao".  What is your db collation ?   Try ```->order('title COLLATE utf8_croatian_ci')```  Lijep pozdrav.

Comment: Collation of the ‘title’ column was utf8_general_ci. I've changed 'collation' in 'utf8_croatian_ci' and now everything works just fine. Nikola zahvaljujem!!!

Comment: Unfortunately there is a problem with 'Collections' ->sortBy('title',SORT_ASC,SORT_LOCALE_STRING); does not sort the data correctly.